# "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9" al ejecutar programa simple en Java

Tags: java, array, eclipse

¡Muy buenas!

Veréis, he creado un programa con la intención de que diga si algún valor de un vector de 10 posiciones está repetido o no.

Por el momento he hecho lo siguiente:

```
package activitatsuf4.java;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ex10 {

    // Funció principal.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int MAX = 10;
        int vec[] = new int[MAX];
        int bit = 0;

        int[] vec_lista = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        // Método para ordenar un vector con "Arrays.sort".
        Arrays.sort(vec_lista);

        // Bucle para recorrer el vector y mirar si hay alguno repetido.
        for (int i = 0; i < vec_lista.length; i++) {
            if (vec_lista[i] == vec_lista[i + 1]) {
                bit = 1;
            }
        }

        // Comparar si está ordenado o si no para imprimir si sí o si no.
        if (bit == 1) {
            System.out.println("Hay un valor repetido en el vector.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No hay ningún valor repetido en el vector.");
        }
    }
}
```

El problema viene cuando ejecuto este programa, ya que me aparece este mensaje de error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at activitatsuf4.java.Ex10.main(Ex10.java:21)
```

PD: "Ex10" es mi fichero .java y "activitatsuf4" es mi paquete.

PD2: El error me apunta a la comparación del if: `if (vec_lista[i] == vec_lista[i + 1]) {`.

¡Agradecería un poco de ayuda, muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuando i vale 9, última iteración dado que empiezas en 0, estás haciendo vec_lista[ i + 1], y con esto accedes fuera de los límites del array. Estás en el último elemento, así que no puedes comparar con el siguiente porque el siguiente no está en tu array. Tienes que cambiar esa manera de buscar repetidos, o en el if comprobar antes de acceder a esa posición si i + 1 supera 9. Y es que el último elemento ya no tienes que compararlo con nadie más.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error ocurre porque al hacer esto:

```
        if (vec_lista[i] == vec_lista[i + 1]) {
            bit = 1;
        }
```

Llega un momento en el que el array se desborda (esto es lo que significa la excepción `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`), porque aumentas `1` al índice, llegando a buscar en `vec_lista` los índices `10` y `11` que no existen.

Es como si intentaras hacer algo así:

```
    System.out.println(vec_lista[10]);
```

O algo así:

```
    System.out.println(vec_lista[11]);
```

Ambos casos provocan una `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` porque no hay índices 10 y 11 en el array.

Para probarlo puedes hacer esto:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_lista.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Valor de i+1: "+(i + 1));          
    }
```

**Salida:**

```
Valor de i+1: 1
Valor de i+1: 2
Valor de i+1: 3
Valor de i+1: 4
Valor de i+1: 5
Valor de i+1: 6
Valor de i+1: 7
Valor de i+1: 8
Valor de i+1: 9
Valor de i+1: 10
Valor de i+1: 11
```

---

### Solución *tradicional* a este problema

Te muestro la forma *tradicional*  de comparar si hay repetidos en el array. Para ello hay que abrir un bucle interno y comparar hay dentro.

El código está optimizado también, en el sentido de que no seguirá comparando en el caso de encontrar un repetido, porque he agregado otra condición dentro del bucle: `&& bit!=1`

El código quedaría entoces así:

```
    final int MAX = 10;
    int vec[] = new int[MAX];
    int bit = 0;

    int[] vec_lista = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    // Método para ordenar un vector con "Arrays.sort".
    Arrays.sort(vec_lista);

    // Bucle para recorrer el vector y mirar si hay alguno repetido.
    for (int j=0;j<vec_lista.length && bit!=1;j++) {
        for (int k=j+1;k<vec_lista.length && bit!=1;k++) {
            if (vec_lista[k]==vec_lista[j]){
                //bit cambiará a 1 y saldrá de ambos bucles
                bit=1;
            }
        }
    }
    String msg=(bit == 1) ? "Hay un valor repetido en el vector." : "No hay ningún valor repetido en el vector.";
    System.out.println(msg);
```

Hay otros métodos más *modernos* de hacer esto, usando LAMBDA o `Set` u otros. Te he aportado una respuesta basada en bucles `for`, por ser lo que presentabas en tu código.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

```
package activitatsuf4.java;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ex10 {

    // Funció principal.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final int MAX = 10;
        int vec[] = new int[MAX];
        int bit = 0;

        int[] vec_lista = { 1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        Arrays.sort(vec_lista);

        //agregale -1 al final de vec_lista.length y listo
        //si no cuando el for llega al final y vos le sumas 1 te caes
        for (int i = 0; i < vec_lista.length-1; i++) {
            if (vec_lista[i] == vec_lista[i + 1]) {
                bit = 1;
            }
        }

        // Comparar si está ordenado o si no para imprimir si sí o si no.
        if (bit == 1) {
            System.out.println("Hay un valor repetido en el vector.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No hay ningún valor repetido en el vector.");
        }
    }
}
```